# I'm trying to find a formula to calculate the sum of averages based on an individual person

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having the hardest time trying to figure out what formula to use to calculate the sum of each of my employees averages based on different audit percentage scores they receive without having to individually use =average and selecting each of their scores. Their names & score placements vary depending on each audit so it would need to be across all columns.

Here is the link to a sample https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nVAPaU5qmOva5M0-L1ouUfATOJaDcPhwTFpmAUlTBo0/edit?pli=1#gid=0

| + | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Employees | QA Accuracy | Expected Results | 7-Eleven Match |  | Aldi Match |  | SE Grocers Match |  |
| 2 | John |  | 93.33% | Employee | QA Accuracy | Employee | QA Accuracy | Employee | QA Accuracy |
| 3 | Amy |  | 95.00% | John | 100.00% | Amy | 100.00% | John | 90.00% |
| 4 | Steven |  | 90.00% | Amy | 95.00% | Steven | 100.00% | Steven | 100.00% |
| 5 | Erin |  | 93.33% | Steven | 70.00% | Erin | 80.00% | Erin | 100.00% |
| 6 |  |  |  | Erin | 100.00% | John | 90.00% | Amy | 90.00% |

I'm still learning formulas and I thought a combination of maybe average and vlookup could help but, I have no clue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The shared sheet has *restricted access*

Comment: Sorry i just realized! I'm going to change it!

Comment: I had to remake the sheet! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nVAPaU5qmOva5M0-L1ouUfATOJaDcPhwTFpmAUlTBo0/edit?pli=1#gid=0

Comment: Post example data that we can copy in your question, we don't download files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=arrayformula(average(if(D:H=A2,E:I,)))
```

[image]